# cPanel "Manual or pull deployment" worked only once and stopped working

Tags: git, gitlab, cpanel, web-deployment

To connect local repo with my server site I use "Manual or pull deployment": https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-deployment/

It worked super smooth for the first time.
But then when I continued doing commits and pulling them from github to my site the "Deploy Head commit" button stopped working...

The reason which is written is:

```
The system cannot deploy
For deployment, ensure that your repository meets the following requirements:

1. A valid .cpanel.yml file exists. For more information, read our documentation.
2. No uncommitted changes exist on the checked-out branch.
```

As for the .cpanel.yml file, it is definitely ok because it worked perfectly fine for the first time and because all the instructions in it were made exactly as were expected.

But I do not understand regarding "uncommitted changes". I do not do any changes on my checked-out-branch I only do pull into it from github as per instruction. So what is it about?

How can I get deployment to work again?

Comment: I think you may be mistaken about what the checked-out branch is. It is the branch in your git repository where cPanel will pull the code from. In order for there to be new code to pull, you must have made some changes.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? I may be having the same issue. I'm sure that my .cpanel.yml file is correct, and I am sure that I do not have any uncommitted changes in the checked-out branch.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the problem is that the .cpanel.yml file is not included in the git repository. if you put it in .gitignore no problem, but don't do "git rm --cache .cpanel.yml" !

make sure you have entered .cpanel.yml into the repository with the command:

```
git add .cpanel.yml
git commit -m 'add .cpanel.yml even though it is ignored or maybe not added yet'
git push
```

Answer (score -2):

To authenticate or clone your GitHub repository via SSH, kindly remove the ".git" at the end of the URL and it will work just fine.

Example: use "git@github.com:username/repository" instead of "git@github.com:username/repository.git"

Please note that an SSH (public) key is required; Repository->Settings->Deploy keys.

@Solomon Oki Ochepa - Oki Technologies Ltd.

Comment: How do you know that this solves OPs problem?

Comment: If I can recall, there is no place I said this answer solved the problem. I'm only providing a solution that works for me.

Thanks.